# Um vetor genérico só funciona se for com ponteiros? Por quê?

Tags: c, genéricos, void

Olá,

Eu sei que isso funciona:

```
typedef struct stack TStack;
struct stack
{
    int size;
    int top;
    void **S; // <------ vai apontar para um vetor de ponteiros 
              // tipo void*, que pode ser de qualquer tipo
};
```

Mas por que não posso fazer:

```
typedef struct stack TStack;
struct stack
{
    int top;
    void S[10]; // <----- de modo que S guarde qualquer coisa
};
```

Ou seja, pra mim fazer um TAD pilha genérico, por exemplo, a única forma de fazê-lo é usando `void*`? Não tem como apenas declara que o vetor é genérico?

Assim como fazemos com `int vet[5];`? Se não, por qual motivo?

Comment: Só para deixar um comentário meio solto, `void **S` não é um vetor.

Comment: @isac, sim, `void **S` não é um vetor, ele é um ponteiro do tipo p-to-p (ponteiro para ponteiro). Nesse caso acima eu não mostrei, mas usei um malloc para alocar um vetor de ponteiros do tipo `void*`, e S aponta pra esse vetor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Os tipos void e void*

**void** e **void*** na verdade são tipos bem diferentes.

O **void** significa "**nada**", portanto não ocupa espaço nenhum na memória do computador. Por isso é usado como valor de retorno de funções que não precisam retornar nada.

O **void*** é um **ponteiro** para algo indeterminado. Quando você for usá-lo para algo, vai precisar de um cast para o tipo real. O tamanho do void* é o tamanho de um ponteiro normal (ou do maior ponteiro possível, no caso de arquiteturas onde existem ponteiros de tamanhos diferentes). O void* ocupa espaço na memória, já o void não.

#### Por que não faz sentido um vetor de void

Um vetor/array em C é uma seqüência de bytes representando vários objetos de mesmo tipo um depois do outro. Então, se void ocupa 0 bytes, void vet[5] ocupa 0 bytes e void s[10] ocupa 0 bytes também (mas veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void).

Mas faz, sim, sentido ter um ponteiro para uma área de memória qualquer, que será reinterpretada mais tarde, por isso void* é válido.

Nota: embora C faça vetores e ponteiros se confundirem em várias situações, eles continuam sendo tipos diferentes e de vez em quando a gente se depara com esses casos.

Um construção que é válida e que pode ser o que você precisa é fazer um vetor de ponteiros void*. Nesse caso a sintaxe fica:

```
void *s[10]; // Leia como: vetor de 10 ponteiros void*
```

#### Como obter um bloco de memória qualquer

Ao contrário de void, que tem tamanho 0, char tem tamanho 1, então se você precisa de um tipo "seqüência de bytes da memória sem se importar com o tipo", use char[] (ou unsigned char[]). Se bem que nesse caso uma outra solução é chamar malloc() para alocar memória dinamicamente.

Entretanto, trocar void[] por char[] (ou malloc) não é exatamente uma solução completa para seu problema, pois exigirá várias adaptações no código. Por exemplo, no mesmo bloco de 8 bytes cabem dois floats ou apenas um double e você teria que levar isso em conta (use sizeof). Se chamar malloc(), precisará lembrar do free().

#### Suporte a tipos genéricos em C

O suporte a tipos genéricos em C não é muito completo, você precisa construir suas próprias convenções e abstrações ao criar uma biblioteca. Você pode usar ponteiros para abstrair o fato que diferentes tipos têm tamanhos diferentes ou pode tentar colocar tudo num bloco de memória e cuidar para que nele caiba tudo o que você quer. De qualquer forma a solução não vem pronta, como em C++.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `sizeof(void)`? Você verá que ocupa 1 byte. Tanto que `void*` aceita aritmética de ponteiros com elementos de 1 byte de tamanho.

Comment: @marcus não existiria um forma similar utilizando-se do `size_t` ?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É mesmo? Eu lembrava que havia algumas "pegadinhas" quanto ao tamanho do void (que ignorei para não complicar demais a resposta), mas não achava que fosse algo tão absurdo como isso, hahaha. Talvez até devesse ser válido o código da pergunta então, né? Também pensei que poderia ser uma daquelas pequenas diferenças entre C e C++, uma área complicada. Se tiver uma ideia de melhorar a resposta sem mudar a essência, pode propor uma edição. Estou agora sem tempo para reformular.

Comment: @FourZeroFive size_t não é nada além de um número (um número unsigned). Não vejo em que ajudaria.

Comment: @marcus, muito interessante sua resposta. Então `void*` representa um ponteiro que pode apontar pra qualquer coisa, e `void` representa um tipo vazio. São duas coisas diferentes. Agora está mais claro pra mim. Obrigado!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado coloquei um link para o S.O. em inglês sobre o sizeof(void), para quem quiser mais informações sobre os detalhes. Tudo indica que é uma extensão do GCC. Fica mais claro com o link, certo?

Comment: @marcus, engraçado que em todos os cantos que eu testei, `sizeof(void)` sempre me retornava 1 (pelo visto deveriam ser todos baseados no GCC). Tinha isso por garantido da linguagem. Aprendi algo novo hoje graças ao seu link.